# UIGestureRecognizer not sending action to other class

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm trying to send an action from a UIGestureRecognizer on a UIView class to its parent's View Controller.

HomeViewController contains a View that contains several (5) OperationViews.

OperationView extends UIView and looks like such:

```
class OperationView: UIView {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // OperationView is on a view that has HomeViewController as it's controller in StoryBoard
        let swipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: HomeViewController.self(), action: #selector(HomeViewController.operatorWasSwiped(_:)))
        swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = .left

        let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: HomeViewController.self(), action: #selector(HomeViewController.operatorWasSwiped(_:)))

        self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer)
        self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }
```

And in HomeViewController I have this function that's supposed to be called by the UIGestureRecognizers:

```
@objc func operatorWasSwiped(_ sender : UIGestureRecognizer) {
    if (sender.isKind(of: UITapGestureRecognizer.self)) { print("Tapped") }
    else { print("Swiped") }

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue1", sender: nil)
}
```

However, I don't get anything. Not even an error.

I've tried adding the UIGestureRecognizer to each OperationView using an IBOutlet on HomeViewController as such:

```
view1.swipeGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))
view2.swipeGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))
view3.swipeGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))
view4.swipeGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))
view5.swipeGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))

view1.tapGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))
view2.tapGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))
view3.tapGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))
view4.tapGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))
view5.tapGestureRecognizer?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(operatorWasSwiped(_ :)))

view1.addGestureRecognizer(view1.swipeGestureRecognizer!)
view2.addGestureRecognizer(view2.swipeGestureRecognizer!)
view3.addGestureRecognizer(view3.swipeGestureRecognizer!)
view4.addGestureRecognizer(view4.swipeGestureRecognizer!)
view.addGestureRecognizer(view5.swipeGestureRecognizer!)

view1.addGestureRecognizer(view1.tapGestureRecognizer!)
view2.addGestureRecognizer(view2.tapGestureRecognizer!)
view3.addGestureRecognizer(view3.tapGestureRecognizer!)
view4.addGestureRecognizer(view4.tapGestureRecognizer!)
view5.addGestureRecognizer(view5.tapGestureRecognizer!)
```

Where I've added:

```
var swipeGestureRecognizer: UISwipeGestureRecognizer?
var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer?
```

To class variables for OperationView

And that works, but it's far from elegant (imagine if I had to add another view...kinda defeats the point of my previous abstraction)

Any ideas what's happening? Or what I'm missing?

I'm using **Swift 4** and **Xcode 9**

Comment: You need to pass a reference to the already existing instance of a `HomeViewController` to the target of your gestures. Your targets are currently throwaway instances.

Comment: How do I do that? ViewControllers easily know what views they handle, but in terms of MVC, Views don't usually know which ViewController handles them. What approach would you suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating that gesture inside of a method, and the gesture may only live in that scope while the function is called. So technically is disappearing before you use it. So creating the instance of that gesture outside of the method may live while the view exist. If that makes sense.

UPDATE: As pointed from the comments, we do need a current reference of the parent viewController.

How about doing it this way..

```
class OperationView: UIView {

let swipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    if let parentViewController = parentViewController {
    swipeGestureRecognizer.addTarget(parentViewController, action: #selector(HomeViewController.operatorWasSwiped(_:)))
    swipeGestureRecognizer.direction = .left

    tapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(parentViewController, action: #selector(HomeViewController.operatorWasSwiped(_:)))

    self.addGestureRecognizer(swipeGestureRecognizer)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    }

   }
}

extension UIView {

var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
    var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self

    while parentResponder != nil {
        parentResponder = parentResponder!.next

        if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
            return viewController
        }
    }
    return nil
   }
}
```

Comment: Still seems to be missing a reference to the currently active HomeViewController. Is this working for you? 'Cus it didn't work for me.

Comment: This answer has the same problem as the original code. It's creating useless instances of `HomeViewController` as the target of each gesture.

Comment: @J Arango, still makes me think I've backed myself into a wall since this seems more like a hack then a regular pattern. Which makes me want to reassess my architecture. However, this does work, so thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, this is a hack lol, there is a better way of doing this but I do not know how you are approaching the architecture of your app. One way of doing it is adding all your views into an IBOutlet collection, and interacting through them adding each view the gesture recognizer. This way there is reference of the UIViewController that holds them.